# asp.net how to decrypt each label value in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, encryption, label

i have an gridview that retrieves the data via a datatable like this:

```
    protected DataTable allClients() 
{
    string conn, comm, tSub, tMain;
    tSub = "client_sub";
    tMain = "client_main"; 

    conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localsqlserver"].ConnectionString;
    comm = "SELECT * FROM [" + tSub + "] t1 LEFT JOIN [" + tMain + "] t2 ON " +
                "t1.customer_ID = t2.customer_ID";

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comm, connection);
    connection.Open();

    DataTable allTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(allTable);

    connection.Close();
    return allTable;
}

clientGrid.DataSource = allClients();
    clientGrid.DataBind();
```

and its working fine on retrieving the data but **the problem is i am trying to decrypt the value on retrieving it**.

i used this  [encryptor class](http://%3ahttp://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/05/21/encrypting-data-in-net-applications.aspx)

so how can decrypt the value of each row in the gridview.

using asp.net 4.0, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options - you can loop around the data table in your allClients() method before returning it, or you can look into handling the row bound events when you do the data bind on the grid view - this would allow you to access each row as its created in the grid view and manipulate the data displayed.

Comment: And yet another option is to write your own field inherited from `BoundField` and overriding `FormatDataValue` to decrypt the cell value.

Comment: @VinayC - i tried adding a BoundField but ended up with this error. `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character,`

Comment: @Moo - tried looping through the datatable like this         `foreach (DataRow dRow in allClients().Rows)Response.Write(Encryptor.Decrypt(dRow["name"].ToString()));}` but got this error `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: Put a break point on the return statement, and see just what columns are in the table - you might be pleasantly surprised...

Comment: @Moo - maybe i should have done that first, anyway thank you.